# Calling a method from another class: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Tags: c#, monogame

I'm creating a method that moves a sprite across the screen depending on what key is pressed

```
class InputController
{
    public void DetectInput (Vector2 position)
    {
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
        {
            position.Y -= 1;
        }

        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
        {
            position.Y += 1;
        }

        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
        {
            position.X -= 1;
        }

        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
        {
            position.X += 1;
        }
```

Trying to call if from my other class, I get an error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>
> InputController was null

Here is the relevant code from the other class

```
private InputController InputController;

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    InputController.DetectInput(_position);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that InputController == null. Probably somewhere in your code, this isn't being run:

```
InputController = new InputController();
```

Comment: Ah I seee so I have to decare in my Update method that "InputController = new InputController();"  Thank you

Comment: It doesn't strictly have to be created in the Update method, but you do have to create an InputController at some point before you use InputController.DetectInput